# Can Twitter Boostrap be made more mobile-friendly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My site's CSS is currently taken care of by Twitter Bootstrap, and it looks/works great at high resolutions such as the one of my 1920x1200 monitor. However, as soon as I go to a smaller device such as a smartphone, and even my very high resolution iPad 3, I notice all sorts of quirks that were simply not there on my computer screen. I can of course simulate them by resizing the browser window down horizontally.

The quirks are generally some form of random resizing (the images will resize before the header text) and eventually everything turning into one single big column, which is pretty much useless and inscrutable to anybody browsing the site.

How do I make the site look exactly the same on smaller screens? Look at [apple.com](http://apple.com) and [nest.com](http://nest.com) and you'll notice that they're both identical on any device you use to visit them.

I know it's Bootstrap trying to be more responsive/fluid, but I feel like that unless I spend a considerable effort fine-tuning that behavior for different horizontal resolutions, I'm much better off showing users the same version on any screen. Is there something I can turn off in Bootstrap that will prevent the smart stacking of spans and will preserve the same shape everywhere?

Thanks a lot!